# javascript timer runs too fast on android in webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

EDIT: I found a solution.  See answers below

---

I wrote a game in html5.  I have the game running using setTimeout(func,1000/FPS).  I then recall the timeout, hence making a loop. (FPS is set to equal 30.)  Everything ran fine in chrome on my android phone, but when I put it into a webview on android, the timers ran what looked like 10 times faster than they did in the browser.  How can I fix this/why is this happening?  Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>

<style>
...
</style>

</head>
<body style="-webkit-user-select:none; cursor:default; margin:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden; position : fixed;">
<script>
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width  = 480;
canvas.height = 800;
canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.style.float = "left";

//canvas.style.transform = "translate3d(0,0,0)";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var started = 0;
var vy = 0;

var startImage = new Image();
startImage.src = "img/start.png";
startImage.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(startImage,0,0);
    //touchstart
    addEventListener("touchstart",function(e) {
        if(started == 0){
            loadGame();
            started = 1;
        }else{
            vy = -15;
        }
    },false);
};
var bgImage;
function loadGame(){
    bgImage = new Image();
    bgImage.src = "img/background.png";
    bgImage.onload = function(){
        loadPlayer();
    };
}

var player;
var playerX = 64;
var playerY = 0;
var playerHeight = 60;
var playerWidth = 76;

var stopTime = false;
var stopFall = false;

function loadPlayer(){
    player = new Image();
    player.src = "img/hero.png";
    player.onload = function() {
        loadwalls();
    };
}

var walls;
function loadwalls(){
    wall = new Image();
    wall.src = "img/wall.png";
    wall.onload = function() {
        loadGameover();
    };
}

var gameO;
function loadGameover(){
    gameO = new Image();
    gameO.src = "img/gameover.png";
    gameO.onload = function() {
        init();
    };
}

var walls = [];

function draw(){
    canvas.width = 480;
    canvas.height = 800;
    ctx.drawImage(bgImage,0,0);
    ctx.drawImage(player,playerX,playerY);
    for(var i=0;i<walls.length;i++){
        if(walls[i][0] > -200){
            ctx.drawImage(wall,walls[i][0],walls[i][1]);
            ctx.drawImage(wall,walls[i][0],walls[i][1]-839-3.25*playerHeight);
            walls[i][0] -= 4;
            if((walls[i][1] < 785 || vy < 0) && (walls[i][1] > 15 || vy > 0)){
                walls[i][1] += vy;
            }
            if(vy < 10){
            vy += 2;
            }
        }
        if(playerX > walls[i][0]+128-playerWidth && walls[i][2] == 0){
            walls[i][2] = 1;
            score += 1;
        }
        if(playerX < walls[i][0]+128 && playerX > walls[i][0]-playerWidth){
            if(playerY < walls[i][1]-3.25*playerHeight-5 || playerY > walls[i][1]-playerHeight+5){
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }
}

function drawFall(){
    canvas.width = 480;
    canvas.height = 800;
    ctx.drawImage(bgImage,0,0);

    for(var i=0;i<walls.length;i++){
            ctx.drawImage(wall,walls[i][0],walls[i][1]);
            ctx.drawImage(wall,walls[i][0],walls[i][1]-839-3.25*playerHeight);
    }
    ctx.scale(1, -1);
    ctx.drawImage(player,playerX,-playerY-playerHeight);
    ctx.scale(1, -1);    
var score = 0;

var highscore = 0;
var state = window.localStorage.getItem("...."); 
if (state) { 
    highscore = parseInt(state); 
}

var FPS = 30;

function init(){
    var time = 0;
    var wallTime = 0;
    stopTime = false;
    stopFall = false;
    setTimeout(function (){
        if(started == 1){
        playerY = playerHeight/2*Math.sin(time)+canvas.width/2+playerHeight;
        draw();
        time+=0.1;
        wallTime += 0.1;
        if(time > Math.PI*2){
            time = 0;
        }
        if(wallTime >= 10){
            walls.push([480,Math.random()*(800-3.25*playerHeight*2)+5*playerHeight,0]);
            wallTime = 0;
        }
        }
        if(!stopTime){
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000/FPS);
        }
    },1000/FPS);
    setTimeout(function(){
        var advert=document.getElementById("ad");
        advert.style.top = "0";
    },1000);
    document.getElementById('iad').src += '';
}

function gameOver(){
    stopTime = true;
    var fallSpeed = 5;
    var fall = setTimeout(function(){
        playerY+=fallSpeed;
        fallSpeed += 1;
        playerX+=5;
        drawFall();
        if(playerY>800+50){
            stopFall = true;
            canvas.width = 480;
        canvas.height = 800;
        canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(gameO,0,0);
        walls = [];
        if(score > highscore){
            window.localStorage.setItem(".....", ""+score);
            highscore = score;
        }
        score = 0;
        vy = 0;
        playerX = 64;
        playerY = 0;
        started = 0;
        var advert=document.getElementById("ad");
        advert.style.top = ""+parseInt(canvas.style.height);
        }
        if(!stopFall){
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000/FPS);
        }
    },1000/FPS);
}
</script>
<div id="ad" style="height:200px; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; top:-200;left:0;"><iframe src="ads/ad.html" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" id="iad" onload="this.width = window.innerWidth;" height="200"></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fascinating. Mind posting how the value of FPS is calculated?

Comment: PLease show your relevant code.

Comment: oh god, I'm an idiot.  I'll add the code

Comment: @Turnsole, FPS is a constant set to 30

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: This happens in my android 4.1.2 x86 emulator and on my Physical Android 4.2.2 tablet

Comment: Could you put an example off the issue up on jsbin.com?

Comment: I just fixed it with requestAnimationFrame(func).  I don't know why setTimeout() was running so fast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, requestAnimationFrame() runs fine on Android, but setTimeout() runs way faster than expected. For anybody else with this issue, and because requestAnimationFrame() is more accurate and efficient than set interval/timeout, just replace all

```
setTimeout(func,1000/FPS);
```

with

```
//it will (try to) run at a constant 60 FPS
requestAnimationFrame(func);
```

Comment: And for older devices that don't support it, see this: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/